# Emacs regexp replace situation

Tags: regex, emacs, replace

on emacs

Let say that I have this text:

`abcd abcd. 23` where `. 2` is important for catching

With `\. [[:digit:]]` I can catch pattern but how to replace without `.`

Output should be `abcd abcd 23`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use capturing groups to retain the numeral.

```
Replace regexp:  \. ([[:digit:]])
Replace regexp with:  \1
```

The `\1` refers to the numeral captured using `([[:digit:]])`.

Comment: yes, that is answer, thank you.
on Emacs it will be
regexp \. \\([[:digit:]]\\)
regexp with:  \1